# How to map an ABI interface to an object of functions in Typescript?

Tags: typescript, ethereum, solidity, typescript-typings, smartcontracts

Take for instance an ABI like this:

```
const abi = [
  {
    name: "myFirstFunction",
    inputs: [
      {
        name: "param1",
        type: "string"
      }
    ],
    outputs: [
      {
        name: "value1",
        type: "string"
      },
      {
        name: "value2",
        type: "number"
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

What I want to achieve is an object type containing the functions defined in the ABI, like this:

```
Type MyABIFunctions = {
  myFirstFunction: (param1: string) => [value1: string, value2: number]
}
```

Is something like this possible in Typescript?

Answer (score 0):

You could use this npm package: [ethereum-abi-types-generator](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ethereum-abi-types-generator)

For each different solidity framework, it has different commands. For example for ethers I wrote this script in package.json:

```
  "genContractType": "abi-types-generator './public/NftMarket.json' --output='./types' --name=nftMarket --provider=ethers_v5",
```

this will generate a file for the types of your abi

Answer (score 0):

Another option is to generate a complete dAPP smart contract clients with [0xWeb](https://github.com/0xweb-org/0xweb).

If you develop your contract, you can generate a TypeScript class from the ABI json

```sh
0xweb i ./artifacts/contracts/Foo.sol/Foo.json --name foo --chain eth
```

If you consume a deployed and validated contract, you can generate the class by the address

```
0xweb i 0x123457 --name foo --chain eth
```

That will generate a strongly typed class for the contract, which you can directly use to communicate with the blockchain, by calling the method like this

```js
const foo = new Foo();
const [ value1, value2 ] = await foo.myFirstFunction();
```